# Java VisualVM: How to initialize settings BEFORE a process starts?

Tags: java, profiling, visualvm

**VisualVM** is practically the standalone Netbeans Profiler (which is a **great** tool, by the way).

But what I am missing, is the ability to initialize monitoring settings for a process **before** it starts.

Usually, in VistualVM, one can open a process and start changing settings only when the process is already running. This is a problem when one should want to profile a shorter-term process.

Sadly, [this solution](https://serverfault.com/questions/293632/how-do-i-start-a-process-in-suspended-state-under-linux) doesn't work: A *Java program* doesn't starts "fast enough", and gets suspended before it would be recognized by VisualVM as *such*.

**Is it possible to do somehow?**

*NOTE 1: My current workaround: I added a cmd-line switch to my project: "-W" to wait for an `[enter]` key press.*

*NOTE 2: Strange, the Netbeans Profiler still gives much more realistic profiling results. But it has a bug currently, which forces me to recompile the main project the amount of times of linked projects ;) That'll be 12... And I failed to reproduce the bug.*

Comment: What do you mean by "initialize monitoring settings"? What kind of problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: `@Tomas Hurka`: Usually, in VistualVM, one can open a process and start changing settings only when the process is already running.